# comparing pandas dataframe with different shapes

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I've got 2 dataframes which actually come from fixed field files and I need to find which rows are different.

```
>>> df1 = pd.DataFrame([('1', '2018/01',    389.0, 'U'),
               ('2', '2018/02',     24.0,'A'),
               ('3',   '2017/01',   80.5,'U'),
               ('4', '2017/02', np.nan, 'R')],
               columns=['sequence', 'key', 'field1','field2'],
               )

>>> df2 = pd.DataFrame([('1', '2018/01',    389.0, 'U'),
               ('2', '2018/02',     24.0,'A'),
               ('3',   '2018/03',   90.5,'T'),
               ('4', '2017/02', np.nan, 'R'),
               ('5','2017/01',80.5,'U')],
               columns=['sequence', 'key', 'field1','field2'],
               )
```

The 'sequence' column is irrelevant and can be dropped, I need to match them on the key column.

df3 = df1 != df2

would work if they were the same shape but I get :
ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled DataFrame objects

I've tried a merge, but that gives me more columns

I think I want to reindex the smaller Dataframe with the larger dataframes 'key' column and fill it with NaN.

Then they would be the same shape and I could compare them ;

```
>>> new_index = df2.take([1],axis=1)
>>> new_index
       key
0  2018/01
1  2018/02
2  2018/03
3  2017/02
4  2017/01
```

looks good but

```
df3 = df1.reindex(new_index,1)
```

isn't right

```
df3 = df1.reindex(new_index,['key'])
df3
        key
(2018/01,)  NaN
(2018/02,)  NaN
(2018/03,)  NaN
(2017/02,)  NaN
(2017/01,)  NaN
```

and neither is this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create an index by `key` column in both `DataFrame`s by [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and then [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) for same indices (columns names are same, so it is possible to compare):

```
df2 = df2.set_index('key')
df1 = df1.set_index('key').reindex(df2.index)
print (df1)
        sequence  field1 field2
key                            
2018/01        1   389.0      U
2018/02        2    24.0      A
2018/03      NaN     NaN    NaN
2017/02        4     NaN      R
2017/01        3    80.5      U

df3 = df1 != df2 
print (df3)
         sequence  field1  field2
key                              
2018/01     False   False   False
2018/02     False   False   False
2018/03      True    True    True
2017/02     False    True   False
2017/01      True   False   False
```

Comment: you're welcome. using this neat trick right now on a project.

Answer (score 4):

Use `datacompy` for comparing two dataframes. 
You can install it using `pip install datacompy` for finding unique rows.

```
import datacompy
d=datacompy.Compare(df1,df2,join_columns='key')
print(d.df2_unq_rows)
print(d.df1_unq_rows)
```

you can also get many other statistics about two dataframes by using datacompy.

Find more about datacompy [here](https://capitalone.github.io/datacompy/pandas_usage.html).